# Удалить ячейки по их содержимому

Tags: python, pandas, drop

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '?', 3],
                  [2, '?', 1],
                  [3, '?', 2]], 
columns=['0','1','2'])
df
```

Необходимо удалить все объекты с пропусками ('?')

Comment: dataframe не может содержать не равной длины строки

Comment: приведите в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить. Как уже сказал @splash58 - в DataFrame все строки должны иметь одинаковое число элементов (столбцов)

Comment: Если пропуски в одном столбце, то тогда можно его удалить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если допустить, что в каждой строке нужно удалить одинаковое количество "пропусков", то можно так:

```
df = df.replace("?", pd.NA)
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
```

теперь df:

```
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  1
2  3  2
```

Если количество пропусков в строках - разное, то этот код тоже будет работать, но у вас появятся NaN-значения.

Comment: а зачем здесь apply? ;) `df.replace("?", np.nan).dropna(how="all", axis=1)`

Comment: @MaxU вы уверены?

Comment: вы попробуйте ;)

Answer (score 1):

Удалить значения не выйдет, а вот заменить значения на 0 или NaN - запросто.
Например:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 3],
                   [2, 1, 5],
                   [3, 5, 2]],
                   columns=['0','1','2'])


def replace_value(pd_data: pd.DataFrame, value_to_replace: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    pd_data[pd_data == value_to_replace] = 0
    return pd_data

replace_value(df, 5)
```

Вывод:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  0  3
1  2  1  0
2  3  0  2
```